# How to prevent breaking axis long labels in React Recharts?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I'am using React Recharts (http://recharts.org/en-US/) to show some chart data and I need to show formatted values nearby axis. Axis values is separated by spaces, for example `1 000 000 $`. React Recharts is breaking values into separate lines

[image]

[image]

How to prevent breaking labels and show it fully at the same line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using a tick formatter? I tried to reproduce your problem but it couldn't.

Here is a re-purposed chart that is working just fine for me.

```
<ResponsiveContainer height={400} width="100%">
    <ComposedChart
      height={400}
      width="100%"
      margin={{ top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20 }}
    >
      <CartesianGrid />
      <XAxis dataKey="name" />
      <YAxis
        unit="$"
        dataKey="y"
        tickFormatter={val => val.toLocaleString().replace(/,/g, " ")}
      />
      <Scatter
        name="A school"
        data={[
          { name: "Jill", y: 3000000 },
          { name: "Eve", y: 5000000 },
          { name: "Audrey", y: 1000000 },
          { name: "Jaqueline", y: 7000000 }
        ]}
        fill="#8884d8"
      />
      <Tooltip />
    </ComposedChart>
  </ResponsiveContainer>
```

Let me know if misunderstood your question.

Comment: None-breaking spaces: `tickFormatter={(value) => value.toLocaleString().replace(/ /g, '\u00A0')}`

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the width for tick
For example,

```html
<YAxis tick={{ width: 75 }} tickFormatter={formatter} domain={yDomain} allowDataOverflow/>
```

Comment: `tick={{ width: 75 }}` This did the job for me. Thank you